# Ошибка при сборке Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Добавил библиотеки и при первой же сборке, `Gradle` ошибку выдает:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>
> Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lorg/apache/http/ConnectionClosedException;
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

А в `Gradle Console` пишет:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Вот сами библиотеки:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5'
    compile 'br.com.liveo:navigationdrawer-material:2.5.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

Попробовал перезапустить Android Studio, очистить проект и перекомпилировать, удалить `httpcore-4.0.1.jar` и обратно синхронизировать `gradle` никаких изменений.

Подскажите, пожалуйста в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2):

`HttpClient` не поддерживается в `SDK 23+`.

Добавьте следующее:

```
android {
    ...
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

**P.S.** Либо понизь до `SDK 22-`.